# Aptana Studio 3 Plugin

Tags: eclipse, aptana, aptana3

I'm Web Developer and I use it Aptana since many years ago. I was trying to get the plugin yesterday and I got

http://studio-jenkins.appcelerator.org/job/studio3-feature-development/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/dist/

Connection timeout

Cannot connect to this repository

Comment: Why is this downvoted! Am unable to add the plugin too. Am on Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a server problem from Aptana.
See [Aptana issue Tracker](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-8508)